# Jmeter test is going in infinite loop with error "warn - jmeter.config.csvdataset empty delimiter converted to ' ,'"

Tags: jmeter

I am running jmeter test with 450 users and i have CSV config data set variables set in the script itself and not in csv file.

when i am running the test, after sometime test stop updating the results file but jmeter.log file is updating only with below warning:

**warn - jmeter.config.csvdataset empty delimiter converted to '.'**

Does above warning could make test go in infinite loop as there is no other warnings found in the jmeter log file

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: Can you show your test plan ?

Comment: I have three test plans and I am starting all in batch file, And all three plans have in total 46 different scripts.